# Delphi: is there an RTL function to remove the accents from a string?

Tags: delphi, string, delphi-2009

I need to remove accents from strings, is there a Delphi (2009+) function for this?

I want that my string contains only A-Z a-z 0-9 chars, so I want to remove accents automatically

Like:

```
RemoveAccents(àèÃÜÿñ)
```

that gives

```
aeAUyn
```

etc....

Comment: What Delphi version are you using?

Comment: I updated the question Delphi 2009, unicode.

Comment: [Convert Hi-Ansi chars to Ascii equivalent (é -> e)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891196/convert-hi-ansi-chars-to-ascii-equivalent-e-e-in-delphi2007/1892432#1892432)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, anyway I think it makes sense to leave this because the question is easy to find. I searched before posting but in my search conditions I searched for "removing accents" not for "convert chars to ascii equivalents"...

Comment: @Jeroen. I would agree to leave it for search purposes, even if it seems like a duplicate. (and it directly points to the same answer anyway)

Comment: @François: Maybe we can merge this question e two questions into the first one. Then people searching can get the bigger picture?

Comment: Yes sure, I don't have rights for doing this. it would be the best "refactoring". Just add "removing accents from a string" in the original question.