# Incompatible char and widechar in Delphi

Tags: delphi, char, delphi-2007, widechar

I have a strange problem.

I'm using Delphi 2007 and running it with the `-r` switch. On my computer everything works fine. When I transfer code to another computer I get an error:

> Incompatible types char and widechar.

Maybe I should change some options.

Function that makes the problem:

```
function THcp.ConVertString(s: string): string;
Var i:integer;
    lstr:string;
begin
     lstr:=EmptyStr;
     for i := 1 to Length(s) do
     begin
           case s[i] of
             'Č': s[i]:='C';
             'č': s[i]:='c';
             'Ć': s[i]:='C';
             'ć': s[i]:='c';
             'Š': s[i]:='S';
             'š': s[i]:='s';
             'Đ': s[i]:='D';
             'đ': s[i]:='d';
             'Ž': s[i]:='Z';
             'ž': s[i]:='z';
           end;
           lstr:=lstr+s[i];
     end;
     Result:=lstr;
end;
```

Comment: Do both computers have the same locale?

Comment: Also function is very inefficient with heap allocs. Assign lstr to result at the start of function and then in the loop modify result in place.

Comment: One final point. When reporting an error message, always tell us which line the error occurred on.

Comment: This line 
All lines in case statement

Comment: What is your file format, ansi or utf8?

Comment: See also: [Convert Hi-Ansi chars to Ascii equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891196)

Comment: And what about the locales?

Comment: as far as in 2007 String is AnsiString, using the function as function ConVertString(s: Ansistring): Ansistring; it won't complite too, since  s[i] is AnsiChar and some of the characters are Unicode/WideString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my hypothesis. On the machine on which the code compiles, the non-ASCII characters in the code are all valid ANSI characters for that machine's locale. But the other machine uses a different locale under which some of those characters are not included in the >= 128 portion of the codepage. And hence those characters are promoted to `WideChar` and so of course are not compatible with `AnsiChar`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this could very much be the reason [David suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276574/757830).

If you declare the function like this:

```
function THcp.ConVertString(s: AnisString): AnsiString;
```

Then that reason yet only applies for the character constants in your code, not for the input. By elimination of those constants by using the character order instead, like I once did in [these routines](http://www.nldelphi.com/Forum/showthread.php?p=295849#post295849), then I suppose this will compile.

```
function AsciiExtToBase(Index: Byte): Byte; overload;
const
  Convert: array[128..255] of Byte = (
  //128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146
  //  €       ‚   ƒ   „   …   †   ‡   ˆ   ‰   Š   ‹   Œ       Ž           ‘   ’
  //  E       ,   f   "               ^       S   <           Z           '   '
     69,129, 44,102, 34,133,134,135, 94,137, 83, 60,140,141, 90,143,144, 41, 41,
  //147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165
  //  “   ”   •   –   —   ˜   ™   š   ›   œ       ž   Ÿ       ¡   ¢   £   ¤   ¥
  //  "   "       -       ~       s   >           z   Y       !
     34, 34,149, 45,151,126,153,115, 62,156,157,122, 89,160, 33,162,163,164,165,
  //166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184
  //  ¦   §   ¨   ©   ª   «   ¬   *   ®   ¯   °   ±   ²   ³   ´   µ   ¶   ·   ¸
  //  |           c   a   <       -                   2   3   '
    124,167,168, 99, 97, 60,172, 45,174,175,176,177, 50, 51, 41,181,182,183,184,
  //185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203
  //  ¹   º   »   ¼   ½   ¾   ¿   À   Á   Â   Ã   Ä   Å   Æ   Ç   È   É   Ê   Ë
  //  1       >               ?   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   C   E   E   E   E
     49,186, 62,188,189,190, 63, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 67, 69, 69, 69, 69,
  //204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222
  //  Ì   Í   Î   Ï   Ð   Ñ   Ò   Ó   Ô   Õ   Ö   ×   Ø   Ù   Ú   Û   Ü   Ý   Þ
  //  I   I   I   I   D   N   O   O   O   O   O   x       U   U   U   U   Y
     73, 73, 73, 73, 68, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79,120,216, 85, 85, 85, 85, 89,222,
  //223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241
  //  ß   à   á   â   ã   ä   å   æ   ç   è   é   ê   ë   ì   í   î   ï   ð   ñ
  //      a   a   a   a   a   a   a   c   e   e   e   e   i   i   i   i   o   n
    223, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 99,101,101,101,101,105,105,105,105,111,110,
  //242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255
  //  ò   ó   ô   õ   ö   ÷   ø   ù   ú   û   ü   ý   þ   ÿ
  //  o   o   o   o   o   /       u   u   u   u   y       y
    111,111,111,111,111, 47,248,117,117,117,117,121,254,121);
begin
  if Index < 128 then
    Result := Index
  else
    Result := Convert[Index];
end;

function AsciiExtToBase(AChar: AnsiChar): AnsiChar; overload;
begin
  Result := Chr(AsciiExtToBase(Ord(AChar)));
end;

function AsciiExtToBase(const S: AnsiString): AnsiString; overload;
var
  P: PByte;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := S;
  P := @Result[1];
  for I := 1 to Length(Result) do
  begin
    P^ := AsciiExtToBase(P^);
    Inc(P);
  end;
end;
```