# How to convert an accented Unicode string to an ANSI string without accent?

Tags: delphi

I have found this [`WideStringToString()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892449/) to convert a Unicode string to an ANSI string. I need to convert a string like `àèéìòù` to `aeeiou`, so all accents should be removed. I think it could be done with that function, but which codepage should I use?

Comment: You could perhaps convert from TEncoding.Unicode to TEncoding.ASCII. The latter will most definitely not contain any accents. See the help for [TEncoding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis except that the accents will likely get converted to `?` instead of their ASCII counterparts. `TEncoding` in not good about performing **transliteration**

Comment: @Remy: It seems to work for the accents in my example code below. But obviously not for foreign characters like epsilon. It is not Google Translate, of course.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891196/convert-hi-ansi-chars-to-ascii-equivalent-%c3%a9-e

Comment: @UliGerhardt: note that the accepted answer uses WideCharToMultiByte, which is used by TEncoding too (on Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current way to do this is to use [System.SysUtils.TEncoding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding). An example:

```pascal
function RemoveAccents(const Src: string): string;
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  Bytes := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Src);
  Result := TEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Bytes);
end;

procedure Test;
begin
  Writeln(RemoveAccents('Ŧĥε ｑùíçķ ƀřǭŵņ fôｘ ǰűmpεď ōvêŗ ţħě łáƶÿ ďơǥ'));
  Writeln(RemoveAccents('àèéìòù'));
end;
```

For some unknown reason this couldn't convert the epsilon (ε), so the output is:

```
Th? quick brown fox jump?d over the lazy dog
aeeiou
```

Comment: I tested with NormalizeString and it does not normalize ε either. I looked [here](https://www.unicode.org/charts/beta/normalization/chart_Greek.html) to see if it is expected but I didn't understand anything from that chart.

Comment: @Sertac: I think it says that epsilon is never composed, i.e. always a single value codepoint. But well, several of these look like an epsilon, so it is pretty confusing. <g>

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your advices! Epsilon will not occur in my data, so this is a suitable solution!